# Unable to run app on device

Tags: android, error-handling

```
I ran my app on virtual emulator and it ran fine. However when I tried to run it on a device, the app stops working. 

The manifest file is as follows:

 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity2">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity_3">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Taskplanner" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity_4" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

I added intent filters to the manifest files however the app is still not running. On starting the app on device the app instant closes showing the message **app has stopped working**.

```
Main_Activity.java- This activity contains a basic info and is linked to 2 other activites Activity2.java and Task.java when the buttons are clicked.

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        }

        public void onclick(View view)
        {
            Intent i=new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        public void gotoplanner(View view)
        {
            Intent i=new Intent(this,Taskplanner.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }

 Activity2.java- This activity is linked to the mainactivity and Activity3.java through buttons. It passes a message through an intent to Activity3.java.

       public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

        String[] citynames={"Ahmedabad","Agra","Amritsar","Bangalore","Bhopal","Bhubaneshwar","Chandigarh","Chennai","Dehradun","Delhi","Gangtok","Goa","Hyderabad","Jaipur","Kochi","Kolkata","Lucknow","Mumbai","Patna","Pune","Shillong","Simla","Srinagar","Trivandrum","Udaipur"};
        Spinner spinner;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);


    //Getting the instance of Spinner and applying OnItemSelectedListener on it

            Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerto);
            spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    //Creating the ArrayAdapter instance having the citynames list
            ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,citynames);
            aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            ArrayAdapter aa2 = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,citynames);
            aa2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner
            spinner2.setAdapter(aa2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), citynames[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        public void gotohome(View view)
        {
            Intent i=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        public void gotoinfo(View view)
        {
            spinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerto);
            String spin=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Intent i=new Intent(this,Activity_3.class);
            i.putExtra("Message",spin);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    }

Activity3.java-his activity is linked to the Activity2.java and Activity4.java through buttons. It passes a message through an intent to Activity4.java.

    public class Activity_3 extends AppCompatActivity {

        private ListView listplace;
        private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
        private ArrayAdapter adapter;
        String Message;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_3);

            databaseHelper= new DatabaseHelper(this);

            Bundle data=getIntent().getExtras();
            if(data==null)
            {
                return;
            }
            Message=data.getString("Message");

            Bundle data2=getIntent().getExtras();
            if(data2==null)
            {
                return;
            }
            Message=data.getString("Message");

            Log.d("insert", "inserting data for Place");
    //databaseHelper.save(new Place("Agra","Uttar Pradesh","Hindi,Urdu,Punjabi,English","Hot and dry summers along with mild monsoon and mild winters ","The city is famous for the Mughal cuisine. Pethas from Agra are also very  famous around the country.","Taj Mahotsav, Ram Barat,Taj Literature Festival,Kailash Fair,Gangaur Fair","Buses, Rickshaws and auto rickshaws. One has to take a Tonga a few kilometres away from Taj Mahal."));
            //databaseHelper.save(new Suggestion("Agra","Taj Mahal","Agra Fort","Fatehpur Sikri","Sikandar(Akbar’s Tomb)","Jama Masjid","Mariam’s Tomb","Keetham Lake","Mughal Heritage Walk","Ram Bagh","Mehtab Bagh"));

     Log.d("reading", "reading all data");
            List<Place> listplace = databaseHelper.findAllp();
            for (Place b : listplace) {
                Log.d("data", "ID :" + b.getId() + " | City :" + b.getCity() + " | State :" + b.getState() + "Language :" + b.getLanguage() + " \n| Climate :" + b.getWeather() + " \n| Cuisine :" + b.getCuisine() + " \n| Festival and Fair :" + b.getFandf());
            }

            Log.d("reading", "reading all data");
            List<Suggestion> listsuggestion = databaseHelper.findAll();
            for (Suggestion b : listsuggestion) {
                Log.d("data", "ID :" + b.getId() + " | City :" + b.getCity() + " | Place 1 :" + b.getPlace1());

            }


        }
        public void gotoselect(View view)
        {
            Intent i=new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        public void gotoplannerinformation(View view)
        {
            Intent i=new Intent(this,Activity_4.class);
            i.putExtra("City_Name",Message);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        public void onaddinformation(View view)
        {

                listplace = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listplace);
                Place p = databaseHelper.findOnep(Message);
                Suggestion s = databaseHelper.findOne(Message);
                String[] ans = {"CITY:\n" + p.getCity(), "STATE:\n" + p.getState(), "LANGUAGE:\n" + p.getLanguage(), "CLIMATE:\n" + p.getWeather(), "CUISINE:\n" + p.getCuisine(), "FESTIVALS AND FAIRS:\n" + p.getFandf(), "TRANSPORT:\n" + p.getTransport(), "PLACES:", s.getPlace1(), s.getPlace2(), s.getPlace3(), s.getPlace4(), s.getPlace5(), s.getPlace6(), s.getPlace7(), s.getPlace8(), s.getPlace9(), s.getPlace10()};
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_view, ans);
                listplace.setAdapter(adapter);



        }
    }

Activity4.java:

    public class Activity_4 extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

        String[] no_of_days= {"2 days","3 days"};
        Spinner spinner;
        String city_name;
        String noofdays;

        private DatabaseHelperPlanner databasehelper;
        TextView text2;
        TextView text3;
        TextView text4;
        TextView text5;
        TextView text6;
        TextView text7;
        TextView text8;
        TextView text9;
        TextView text10;
        TextView text11;
        TextView text12;
        TextView text13;
        TextView text14;
        TextView text15;
        TextView text16;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_4);

            //Spinner
            spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.days);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,no_of_days);
            aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(aa);

            Bundle data=getIntent().getExtras();
            if(data==null)
            {
                return;
            }
            city_name=data.getString("City_Name");

            databasehelper=new DatabaseHelperPlanner(this);

            Log.d("insert", "inserting data for Place");
     databasehelper.save(new Planner("Ahmedabad","3 days","Day 1:","10 :00 am-Sabarmati Ashram (8:30 am- 6:30 pm)- People usually take 2 hours visiting the Ashram.",
                    "12:30 pm-Sabarmati River Front (6:00 am-10:00 pm)-People usually spend around half an hour here.","3:00 pm-Adalaj Stepwell (8:00 am– 7:00 pm)- People usually take 30 minutes to 1 hour to visit the Stepwell.","","","Day 2:","9:00 am-Kankaria Lake (9:00 am -10:00 pm)- People usually take an hour to visit the Lake.","11:30 am-Hutheesing Jain Temple (8:00 am -8:00 pm)- People usually take around an hour to visit the temple","2:30 pm-Bhadra Fort(9:00 am-5:00pm)-People usually take an hour to visit the Fort."
                    ,"5:00 pm-Sarkhej Roja(9:00 am-6:00 pm)-People usually take an hour to visit the lake.","7:00 pm-Auto World Vintage Car Museum (8:00 am-9:00pm)- People spend around one to two hours here.","DAY 3:","10:00 am-Calico Museum of Textiles (10:15 am-12:30 pm (Wednesday Closed))-People usually spend two hours here.","5:30 pm- Akshardham Temple (9:30 am – 7:30 pm)-People usually take 2-3 hours to visit the Temple."));

    Log.d("reading", "reading all data");
            List<Planner> listplann = databasehelper.findAll();
            for (Planner b : listplann) {
                Log.d("data", "ID :" + b.getId() + " | City :" + b.getCity() + " | Days :" + b.getDay());
            }





        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), no_of_days[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void gototravelinfo(View view)
        {
            Intent i=new Intent(this,Activity_3.class);
            i.putExtra("Message",city_name);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        public void gotonextpage(View view)
        {

            noofdays=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

            Planner planner = databasehelper.findOne(city_name,noofdays);

            text2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);
            text3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text3);
            text4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text4);
            text5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text5);
            text6=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text6);
            text7=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text7);
            text8=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text8);
            text9=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text9);
            text10=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text10);
            text11=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text11);
            text12=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text12);
            text13=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text13);
            text14=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text14);
            text15=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text15);
            text16=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text16);
            text2.setText(planner.getOne_view());
            text3.setText(planner.getTwo_view());
            text4.setText(planner.getThree_view());
            text5.setText(planner.getFour_view());
            text6.setText(planner.getFive_view());
            text7.setText(planner.getSix_view());
            text8.setText(planner.getSeven_view());
            text9.setText(planner.getEight_view());
            text10.setText(planner.getNine_view());
            text11.setText(planner.getTen_view());
            text12.setText(planner.getEleven_view());
            text13.setText(planner.getTwelve_view());
            text14.setText(planner.getThirteen_view());
            text15.setText(planner.getFourteen_view());
            text16.setText(planner.getFifteen_view());
        }
    }



The logcat shows the following error on running the app on device.



     E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
 E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.
```

When the same app is run on virtual emulator the app works fine. Initially i had not added the intent filters but even after adding them to the manifest file the app does not work on the device

Comment: i guess you are having a service and didnot mention it in manifest

Answer (score 0):

You need to define service class in Manifest like this:

```
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```